# joomla specific component displaying blank page

Tags: php, joomla

I try to access my custom components on view and sub controller like

```
http://www.whizzrd.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_osservicesbooking
```

I have tried everything, still i didn't know what is the error.

1.added this code on `com_yourcomponent/yourcomponent.php`

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

2. enable `debug` in `global configuration` and set the `error_report` to `development`

but I'm still getting blank pages. still not yet find the error
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Have you assigned your component view to a menu item? You need to do this to be able to see it

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Global Configuration` in Admin panel and `Server` Tab and there do `Error Reporting` to `Maximum`.

Doing this setting you will be able to **view the error** you are getting.

> Global Configuration-> Server-> Error Reporting -> Maximum

Comment: @Nodemon, Try to clean your browser cache once

Comment: Do you have any `default controller` set, and in that controller have you set your `default view`

Comment: i didnt understand what you saying am new to joomla

Comment: Have you developed your component in joomla 3, also if all this is not working then we need to check your basic files like `controller.php, osservicesbooking.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding your view name.

http://www.whizzrd.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_osservicesbooking&view=osservicesbookings

Also check filename and component names if it seems differ or capital.

Comment: If above all true in your case then please provide component zip or files so that we can check and give you feedback @Nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had typed `defined('__JEXEC') or die` (two underlines before JEXEC) and it is supposed to be `defined('_JEXEC') or die` and as I had not set a message for `die` it basically just displayed a blank page with nothing. Took me a couple of hours to figure it out. Best thing I did was to start adding a different message in my `die` statements and then it will display the die message of the page with errors.